# Workgroup Templates not updating for all users (Microsoft Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, dropbox, templates, workgroup

I have set up company wide templates and save them in Workgroup_Templates folder on drop box.  Each user sets Word to get Workgroup Templates from the same folder, which is a path like this

```
C:\Users\Jo\Dropbox (Company name)\Company Team Folder\Templates\Workgroup_Templates
```

The contents of that folder are maintained the same on all computers as Dropbox syncs changes across each computer.

We use Office 365 on all computers.

A colleague has an issue that the templates available from Word - New - `Workgroup_Templates` are not updating and have old versions of the templates, even though the Dropbox folder of their local computer is synced and up to date (i.e. when we navigate via file explorer, the correct templates are there).

There are slight variations in that users experience to mine.  When I click 'New' I get two options: FEATURED and CUSTOM.  Clicking on custom takes me to `Workgroup_Templates`.  The other user's options are FEATURED and SHARED.  Clicking Shared takes them to `Workgroup_Templates`.

We've been through file locations in Word (Advanced - File locations) and have searched their computer for a duplicate copy of the `Workgroup_Templates` folder in case somehow Word has created a cached copy somewhere.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you certain they are running Office 365 and not a volume license version of Office 2016? If they are on Office 365, is the update channel the same? Some update Monthly, others Quarterly or Semi-Annual.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The first part (why one user has featured and shared options and the other has featured and custom) is due to one user having a modified personal templates section. This for some reason changes the title of the options.

The second part is actually that the templates are updating, but for some reason when selecting a template (from clicking new, rather than navigating to the template in explorer) Word only displays the title of the template up to a full stop.  Therefore 'Report Template v1.2' displays as 'Report Template v1'.